# Why does SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED on Postgresql take a long time?

Tags: postgresql

Our Postgres 9.2.4 server is taking 0.69s on average (15000 statements) to execute

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED
```

Why should this be?

Would using `INITIALLY DEFERRED` in the table definition and not using `SET CONSTRAINTS ..` eliminate this time or just hide it somewhere else?

Comment: How did you measure that time? Does this include the client/server communication overhead? Why is this a problem at all? How often do you run that statement?

Comment: The time is measured by analysing log files with pgfouine i.e. it is the server side time as reported by Postgres. In a day it executes 15000 times and takes more than 3h in total. This server is inserting/updating many batches of rows and we are trying to increase throughput.

Comment: Why on earth do you execute this statement 15000 times per day?

Comment: It is executed at the start of each batch insert/update transaction. The inserted/updated rows reference each other so we need this to avoid tripping the constraints on each insert/update.

Comment: If you issue this for **every** transaction, then why not set all constraints to `initially deferred`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, this is probably because each time you run this statement, what happens in the background is a big update statement on table definitions located in the pg_catalog. In other words, you add dead rows to the pg_catalog, whichg results in increasingly larger amounts of disc space being visited during the appropriate seq scans.

If you're really running the statement 15k times per day, perhaps you need to give a cold hard look to your schema or workflow?

Comment: Aha. Does that mean that using "INITIALLY DEFERRED" in the table definitions instead would sort this out? The database has more than 5000 tables in 100 or so schemas. I assumed that "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED" would just set a per tx flag and be fast.

Comment: Technically, you're not incorrect. It is indeed setting a flag per constraint each time you edit the tables (back *and* forth). Trouble is, you've a flag per constraint that gets changed. That's a lot of update (i.e. delete + insert) statements; in other words disk accesses. And yes, go with deferrable initially deferred constraints where appropriate if that fixes your problem.

Comment: This is incorrect.  SET CONSTRAINTS does not touch the system catalogs.

Comment: @DavidTinker: you should probably look into (and accept) Peter's response, if you've left this pending.

Answer (score 4):

I looked through the source code.  Essentially, `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` does nothing except set a global variable noting "all appropriate constraints are now deferred".  The only nontrivial work that is done is when there are subtransactions in play.  If that applies to your case, try it without.  (Note that subtransactions include PL/pgSQL exception blocks.)

Comment: Hmm. Well somehow for us '''SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED''' was taking on average 0.69s per transaction. As far as I know we aren't using subtransactions (i.e. not on purpose). We are using the Postgres JDBC driver so maybe that is doing something. We also get '''TRANSACTION ALREADY IN PROGRESS''' warnings in the logs if thats a clue. We have made this issue go away by using '''INITIALLY DEFERRED''' for now.